# In GEE, trying to extract Sentinel-5P causes computational time error while extracting other datasets work quickly

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, sentinel-5p

I'm trying to extract average values over a year from Sentinel-5P around a set of points. I buffer the points, then take average satellite values using the buffered points. This approach works quickly when testing on Sentinel-2 data as well as Landsat 8; however, the process runs into a computational time out error with Sentinel-5P.

I'm wondering if there's just something in particular about Sentinel-5P that causes this process to take a lot longer / fail, or if there's something that I'm doing that's causing the process to be inefficient?

See below code, where I also report the runtime for the code to complete. To summarize the runtime:

- **Extracting Landsat 8:** Runtime: 40s // Batch compute usage: 128.8653 EECU-seconds
- **Extracting Sentinel S2:** Runtime: 1m // Batch compute usage: 1028.0422 EECU-seconds
- **Extracting Sentinel 5P:** [After 20 minute runtime] Error: Computation timed out. (Error code: 3)

```py
# Setup ------------------------------------------------------
## Import / Initalize GEE
import ee
ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()

## Import other packages
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np

## Make dataframe of points
d = {'latitude': list(np.arange(35, 45, .1)), 
     'longitude': list(np.arange(-110, -100, .1))}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['uid'] = range(0, len(df)) 
df['uid'] = df['uid'].astype('str')

## Convert to FeatureCollection and Buffer
buffer_size = 2500

df_list = []

n_rows = df.shape[0]
for i in range(0, n_rows):
    df_i = df.iloc[[i]]

    f_i = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([df_i['longitude'].iloc[0], 
                                        df_i['latitude'].iloc[0]]), 
                     {'uid': df_i['uid'].iloc[0]})

    f_i = f_i.buffer(buffer_size)

    df_list.append(f_i)

df_fc = ee.FeatureCollection(df_list)

# Extract Landsat 8 Data ----------------------------------------------
# Runtime: 40s
# Batch compute usage: 128.8653 EECU-seconds

BANDS = ['SR_B1']

image = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2")\
    .filterDate('2021-01-01', '2021-12-31')\
    .mean()

## Extract values to points
vals = image.reduceRegions(collection = df_fc,
                           reducer = ee.Reducer.mean(),
                           scale = 1000,
                           tileScale = 8)

bands_to_export = BANDS.copy()
bands_to_export.append('uid')
    
task = ee.batch.Export.table.toDrive(collection=vals, 
                                     folder='gee_outputs', 
                                     description='l8_b1.csv', 
                                     fileFormat='CSV',
                                     selectors = bands_to_export)

task.start()

# Extract Sentine-2 Data ----------------------------------------------
# Runtime: 1m
# Batch compute usage: 1028.0422 EECU-seconds
BANDS = ['B1']

image = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")\
    .filterDate('2021-01-01', '2021-12-31')\
    .mean()

## Extract values to points
vals = image.reduceRegions(collection = df_fc,
                           reducer = ee.Reducer.mean(),
                           scale = 1000,
                           tileScale = 8)

bands_to_export = BANDS.copy()
bands_to_export.append('uid')
    
task = ee.batch.Export.table.toDrive(collection=vals, 
                                     folder='gee_outputs', 
                                     description='s2_b1.csv', 
                                     fileFormat='CSV',
                                     selectors = bands_to_export)

task.start()

# Extract Sentinel-5P Data ----------------------------------------------
BANDS = ['CH4_column_volume_mixing_ratio_dry_air']

image = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_CH4")\
    .filterDate('2021-01-01', '2021-12-31')\
    .mean()

## Extract values to points
vals = image.reduceRegions(collection = df_fc,
                           reducer = ee.Reducer.mean(),
                           scale = 1500,
                           tileScale = 8)

bands_to_export = BANDS.copy()
bands_to_export.append('uid')
    
task = ee.batch.Export.table.toDrive(collection=vals, 
                                     folder='gee_outputs', 
                                     description='s5p_ch4.csv', 
                                     fileFormat='CSV',
                                     selectors = bands_to_export)

task.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get `Computation timed out` with `reduceRegions()` you can try to map over the features, and execute `reduceRegion()` for every individual feature. That way, the computation makes faster progress.

This exported for me:

```
vals = df_fc.map(lambda feature: ee.Feature(None, image.reduceRegion(
    reducer=ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry=feature.geometry(),
    scale=1500,
    tileScale=8    
)))
```

Comment: This is great -- seems to take longer, but avoids the error. The one issue is that the outputted csv file doesn't contain the "uid" from the dataframe. (It contains a "uid" variable name, but the values are blank).